# For pashupatinath darshan kathmandu by flight return

Tags: air-travel, indian-citizens, nepal

I m a citizen of india..I want to go pashupatinath darshan kathmandu by flight with my family and return from there by flight
I don't have a passport ..I have a driving licence (maharashtra)
And pan card ,adhaar card also have..my wife's have aadhar card and pan card ..my child's aadhar card and school id..4 years old
My father's age 74 they have voter ID card and aadhar card pan card..my mother 55 also have voter ID and aadhar card pan card
Can I travel to pashupatinath mandir.kathmandu by flight in April..